# Защита метаданных в il2cpp

Tags: unity3d, защита

Некоторые время я имел дело со взломом игр на Юнити. Ничего особо сложного: взял il2cpp dumper, закинул в него libil2cpp.so и globalmetadata.dat. Получил дамп с оффсетами и делай с ними что хочешь. Но иногда попадались игры у которых была особенная метадата. Если её закинуть в дампер, то мне выдаст ошибку некорректной метадаты. Вот теперь я написал свою игру. Скомпилировал под il2cpp, и конечно же там та же уязвимость, метадата. Хочу тоже защитить её. Как можно такое сделать?